# Using a different viewport meta tag for iPad vs everything else?

Tags: javascript, html, meta

I'm using this metatag on my site:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5">
```

That scale makes things work just perfectly on iPhones (which I know is unorthodox... not using 1), but when the user agent is an iPad what I'd like to do is serve this:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Just wondering if any of you guys have clever ideas for how I might do so? Thanks so much!